# MuParser doesn't work in visusl studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mathematical-expressions

Hi I need to use muParser (c# wrapper) for some Mathematical expressions. In vs 2010 it works good but in vs 2012 the program terminates without any error message.
Has anyone faced such problem? Any solution?